# Get Product id from order id in Woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I am having trouble with Woocommerce product details and order details relationship. I'm not able to find the product ID of a related order ID on the *View Orders* page of the Woocommerce theme. I simply want to get the product content and permalink etc on *View Orders* page.

I tried searching in `wp_postmeta` but had no luck.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### WooCommerce 3.0+

you can get the order items of an order by

```php
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
```

then if you loop through the items, you can get all the relevant data:

```php
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item->get_name();
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
}
```

a good tip is to check how the admin order pages get the data, you'll find many answers there!

### Pre-WooCommerce 3.0

```php
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't appear to work in the latest version of WooCommerce...

Comment: Still works in WooCommerce 2.4.8 for me, but you need to have the $order_id variable defined (sometimes it's in $order->id, depending on your context).

Comment: @mevius i added an edit for 3+ with a dispatch function for checking multiple products

Comment: see edit history for dispatcher, this is not good without it as it will eat up your server pointlessly

Comment: @GaretClaborn that depends entirely on what you're doing with this data. 'as is', this example snippet is not wasteful of memory in any way.

Comment: If you are checking multiple products then you're repeating quite a bit of logic vs being able to capitalize on the first run of the loop

Comment: Note that in many woocommerce templates `$order` already exists

Answer (score 8):

I worked on it and achieved something. That I would like to share to other developers. This is not preferred way to do it, but for knowledge I am posting my answer.

```
global $wpdb;
            $result = $wpdb->get_results('select t1.order_item_id, t2.* FROM 
            wp_woocommerce_order_items as t1 JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as t2 ON t1.order_item_id = t2.order_item_id
            where t1.order_id='.$order->ID);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($result);
            echo '</pre>';
```

hope will help someone.

### Additionally:

Better to use wordpress table prefix to avoid problems in multiple website or in migration etc.

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';
```

Comment: @ErenorPaz Thanks, I added content in answer, in reply to your comment :)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, even on an old thread! I'll delete my previous comments, since it's outdated now :)